# Querying azure analysis services with azure sql database

Tags: azure, ssas, azure-sql-database, azure-analysis-services

Before we moved to Azure we could query SSAS directly from T-SQL:

`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER, SELECT {} ...`

Is it possible to access and query Azure Analysis Services directly from Azure SQL Database ? The solution doesn't have to be as flexible as openquery. All I want to do is skip middle tier (cache Analysis Services results in C# etc) and allow azure sql and analysis services to talk to each other directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't currently available in Azure SQL DB but feel free to request it on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database).

As a side note the Azure SQL DB team appears to be using [CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=dedicated&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762) with TYPE=RDBMS option instead of linked servers. But the list of sources supported in that are very limited so far. Regardless you might keep an eye on that statement in case it is extended in the future.